# How to set firebase read rule and read all siblings if one matches

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, rule

I have set my firebase rules as follows:

```
    {
  "rules": {"users": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"

    }}
  }
}
```

Which allows write only to the node with matching uid and read all child nodes of every uid. But I want it to be like if I query using a child node under uid, only the matching child and it's siblings can be read...

for example this is my json structure:

```
 {
"users" : {

      "AJkK4yZJsoseeefrJ7i6KIOUBDghtrhgthrtDi1" : {
        "lat" : 20.5001,
        "long" : 68.3755,
        "number" : "9876543210",
        "time" : 1499599788090
      }
    }
}
```

I want to query using the number, and set the read rule as can read lat long and time only where the number matches. How to write the rule?

update: my question now is, how to query the database using number and get other siblings if value of number matches in android? I have tried this but not working:}

```
  friend = mDatabase.getReference("users");
  friend.keepSynced(true);


  Query z = LocationActivity.this.friend.orderByChild("number").equalTo("9876054321");

  z.addListenerForSingleValueEvent((new ValueEventListener() {
        long lastseen;
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                for (DataSnapshot zoneSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    lastseen = (Long)zoneSnapshot.child("time").getValue();
                    friendLatitude = (Double) zoneSnapshot.child("lat").getValue();
                    friendLongitude = (Double) zoneSnapshot.child("long").getValue();
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }}
```

it returns value null, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `LocationActivity.this.friend` in that last snippet?

Comment: friend is db reference where LocationActivity is MainActivity

Comment: I can now get the value of my own data from  @Override
               public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                   if(dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue() != null){

                   }
               }
and using a addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() instead, but for others it still is null, how to read that without revealing their uid in snapshot? i.e. Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase read permissions are enforced when you attach a listener. In order to query a node, you must have read permission on that node (as Bradley also explained). So in order to be able to query users, you must have read permission on `/users`. And since any [user that has read permission to `/users` can also read any data under that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade), you cannot use security rules to filter what nodes a user has access to.

This is known as [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) and is one of the common pitfalls for developers new to Firebase security model. I recommend that you read the documentation I linked already and some of the many [questions/answer about the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+rules+are+not+filters).

The simplest solution for your use-case seem to be to pull up the `.read` rule to `users`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: but in this simplest solution anyone with authorization can read all the $uid variables as well as their child and then simply send a setvalue request to delete them. How do I prevent them from doing that? would the auth.uid prevent it or it can also be forged?
also, if i set the phone as parent and put uid under it (swap phone and uid) and allow all child to ".read": "auth != null" except the uid what would the rule be like?

Comment: If you don't want any users to **list** all users, you should keep a separate index (for each user) of the users they can see. So `/friends/$uid: { friend1: true, friend2: true}` etc. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout

Comment: i just want to know whether one can forge the auth.uid himself using a server or de obfuscating my code, please answer as you are directly related with firebase.otherwise there are options to relate one table with verification of authenticity and relating to that with a number in order to write and an another table with primary as phone number to allow read and write only who matches in the former table. But that is no way convenient neither optimized option, rather a do it all for a simple thing.

Comment: Normal users cannot control the `auth.uid` variable in security rules. That would require them to have the ability to [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), which requires having access to the admin credentials of the project.

Comment: Thank You Sir! basically that translates the intruder definition to an expert coder...where the restore from backup is the only option viable...as far as it seems.

Comment: Being able to hack Firebase Auth has nothing to do with their coding experience, but with having access to your admin credentials.

Comment: but then it would take them to be an expert to get my credentials without a heavy ssl decryption using ghs/hr for money even which is not a definite way if the credentials are not human friendly, then recovery options eavesdropping would again cost at-least an usrp board and skills if i set it to my mobile number only, lastly there is social engineering and guess for one who is known to me...otherwise it has to be an internal employee, please don't take it otherwise and let me know if there are other scopes for intrusion available to forge the uid.

Answer (score 1):

In order to query every node, the user needs to have read permission for **ALL** nodes under the parent.

This is because security rules cannot be used to query data in Firebase.

Comment: I know, and I want to read all nodes under each uid, except the uid value itself, otherwise it would be meaningless to check for write permission as anyone could see all the uid values and start manipulation.

Datasnapshot should return only the siblings of the node matching the query and not the parent or child of other parents.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this answers the question, but I found this post looking for the following solution with respect to Firebase Storage .. where I can control which sibling nodes are accessible:

```
  match /uploadRoot/{userId}/{uploadCategory}/{allPaths=**} {

      // allow read access for client upload/download
      allow read, write:
        if request.auth != null
          && request.auth.uid == userId
          && (
              uploadCategory == 'userTextFiles'
              || uploadCategory == 'userImages'
            );
```